# React Native 60 and above margin issue in iOS - Ignoring bogus layer size

Tags: ios, react-native

I have used margin style in older react native projects, no issues with that. Now I am creating new RN project - 0.60.5 version.

```
return(
        <ImageBackground
        style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}
        source={require('../images/bgImage.png')}
      >
         <View style={{backgroundColor:"white",height:"8%",
         borderRadius:5,width:"70%",marginTop:10}}>

         </View>

      </ImageBackground>
    )
```

In above code, after adding `marginTop` in `View` component iOS app hang and displayed the log as

```
Ignoring bogus layer size (179769313), contentsScale 1.000000, backing store size
```

If I remove the `marginTop` style , then the UI will be rendered.

Have anyone has idea about it in React Native iOS? How to solve this?

Comment: Could you try paddingTop??

Comment: @hongdevelop paddingTop works fine for padding. But I want to give margins for my View Component.

Comment: Please give a padding value to your parents' style.

Comment: @hongdevelop I understand your point. My question is why margin styles are suddenly not supported in RN iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Upgrading Xcode to v11.2.1 fixed it.